# Searching for multiple strings in multiple files

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, file, search

I have a text file containing 21000 strings (one line each) and 500 MB of other text files (maily source codes). For each string I need to determine if it is contained in any of those files. I wrote program that does the job but its performance is terrible (it would do that in couple of days, I need to have the job done in 5-6 hours max).
I'm writing using C#, Visual Studio 2010

I have couple of questions regarding my problem:
a) Which approach is better?

```
foreach(string s in StringsToSearch)
{
    //scan all files and break when string is found
}
```

or

```
foreach(string f in Files)
{
    //search that file for each string that is not already found
}
```

b) Is it better to scan one file line by line

```
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(file);
while(!r.EndOfStream)
{
    string s = r.ReadLine();
    //... if(s.Contains(xxx));
}
```

or

```
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(file);
string s = r.ReadToEnd();
//if(s.Contains(xxx));
```

c) Would threading improve performance and how to do that?
d) Is there any software that can do that so I don't have to write my own code?

Comment: do you have to write the program? windows has findstr built in. You can use a for loop that could search these other files in parallel

Comment: Definitely not a correct/complete answer, but don't load all (500MB!) files for each string. Once you have (part of) the file in memory, do all of your actions then.

Comment: I ment to load whole file one by one, not 500 MB of files at once.

Comment: What OS are you on, if you are on Win7 you can search within files automatically and its pretty rapid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to minimize of File I/O, so your first idea is very bad because you would be opening the 'other' files up to 21.000 times. You want to use something based on the second one (a1). And when those other files aren't overly big, load them into memory once with readAllText.

```
List<string> keys = ...;    // load all strings

foreach(string f in Files)
{
    //search for each string that is not already found
    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(f);  //easy version of ReadToEnd


    // brute force
    foreach(string key in keyes)
    {
        if (text.IndexOf(key) >= 0) ....
    }

}
```

The brute force part can be improved upon but I think you will find it acceptable.

Comment: Is if(text.IndexOf(key)>=0) faster than if(text.Contains(key)) ?

Comment: @Ichi: No, I would expect them to be equally fast.

Answer (score 6):

If you are just wanting to know if the string is found or not found, and don't need to do any further processing, then I'd suggest you just use grep. Grep is extremely fast and designed for exactly this kind of problem.

```
grep -f strings-file other-files...
```

should do the trick. I'm sure there is a Windows implementation out there somewhere. At worst, Cygwin will have it.

EDIT: This answers question d)

Comment: Yes, despite the [C#] tag this might be the best approach.

Comment: I'm not familiar with grep and how it works so maybe little help how to use that?

Comment: Grep is a very common tool in *nix systems. There's a lot of documentation out there so there's bound to be a good tutorial somewhere. The suggested command looks for all strings found in "strings-file" in any of the "other-files" and prints out all the matching lines in "other-files". There are many options for changing the output to what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the Windows Search SDK here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965362%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

1. In both a) and b), second option is efficient
2. threading may not improve the performance coz each thread would read the file from your disk, so you disk will become bottleneck.
3. sry i have no idea about s/w for your purpose

thread snippet

```
      foreach (FileInfo file in FileList)
      {
         Thread t  = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ProcessFileData));
         t.Start(file.FullName);  
       }//where processFileData is the method that process the files
```

**General I/O Guidelines**

What follows are some basic recommendations for reducing the I/O activity of your program, and thus enhancing its performance. As with all recommendations, it is important to measure the performance of the code being optimized before and after optimization to ensure that it actually gets faster.

1. Minimize the number of file
   operations you perform
2. Group several small I/O transfers
   into one large transfer. A single
   write of eight pages is faster than
   eight separate single-page writes,
   primarily because it allows the hard
   disk to write the data in one pass
   over the disk surface. For more
   information,
3. Perform sequential reads instead of
   seeking and reading small blocks of
   data. The kernel transparently
   clusters I/O operations, which makes
   sequential reads much faster.
4. Avoid skipping ahead in an empty
   file before writing data. The system
   must write zeroes into the
   intervening space to fill the gap.
   For more information, see  Reading
   is typically cheaper than writing
   data.
5. Defer any I/O operations until the
   point that your application actually
   needs the data.
6. Use the preferences system to
   capture only user preferences (such
   as window positions and view
   settings) and not data that can be
   inexpensively recomputed.
7. Do not assume that caching file data
   in memory will speed up your
   application. Storing file data in
   memory improves speed until that
   memory gets swapped out to disk, at
   which point you pay the price for
   accessing the disk once again.
   Strive to find an appropriate
   balance between reading from disk
   and caching in memory

Answer (score 2):

Does the search have to be real time on current 500 MB of text?
The reason I ask is because you could build a search index on the text files and perform search. It would be much faster...Take a look at Lucene

[Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)

[C# and Lucene to index and search](http://aspcode.net/c-and-lucene-to-index-and-search)

Comment: It doesn't need to be real time search. It is one time task. Do and forget about it :P

Comment: Then use Lucene (I have not used Windows Search SDK) to build a full search index and perform lookups against it...I used Lucene before...It's fast!