# How to Speed Up Reading a File using FileSteam

Tags: c#, performance, stream, filestream

I am facing a performance issue while searching the content of a file. I am using the `FileStream` class to read files (~10 files will be involved for each search with each being ~70 MB in size). However, all of these files are simultaneously being accessed and updated by an another process during my search. As such, I cannot use `Buffersize` for reading files. Using buffer size in `StreamReader` takes 3 minutes even though I am using regex.

Has anyone come across a similar situation and could offer any pointers on improving the performance of file search?

Code Snippet

```
  private static int BufferSize = 32768;
  using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {

            using (TextReader txtReader = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8, true, BufferSize))

            {
                System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex patternMatching = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(.*?)(?=\n\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex dateStringMatch = new Regex(@"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}");
                char[] temp = new char[1048576];
                while (txtReader.ReadBlock(temp, 0, 1048576) > 0)
                {
                    StringBuilder parseString = new StringBuilder();
                    parseString.Append(temp);
                    if (temp[1023].ToString() != Environment.NewLine)
                    {
                        parseString.Append(txtReader.ReadLine());
                        while (txtReader.Peek() > 0 && !(txtReader.Peek() >= 48 && txtReader.Peek() <= 57))
                        {
                            parseString.Append(txtReader.ReadLine());
                        }
                    }
                    if (parseString.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string[] allRecords = patternMatching.Split(parseString.ToString());
                        foreach (var item in allRecords)
                        {

                            var contentString = item.Trim();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contentString))
                            {
                                var matches = dateStringMatch.Matches(contentString);
                                if (matches.Count > 0)
                                {

                                    var rowDatetime = DateTime.MinValue;
                                    if (DateTime.TryParse(matches[0].Value, out rowDatetime))
                                    {
                                        if (rowDatetime >= startDate && rowDatetime < endDate)
                                        {
                                            if (contentString.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(searchText))
                                            {
                                                var result = new SearchResult
                                                {
                                                    LogFileType = logFileType,
                                                    Message = string.Format(messageTemplateNew, item),
                                                    Timestamp = rowDatetime,
                                                    ComponentName = componentName,
                                                    FileName = filePath,
                                                    ServerName = serverName
                                                };
                                                searchResults.Add(result);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return searchResults;
```

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827350/faster-way-of-searching-a-string-in-text-files

Comment: You say multiple files are being accessed and updated by multiple processes, how are you solving your concurrency issue?

Comment: Hi Yacoub, my current search does not bother about any future update in the file. all i need is i need to open that file and search it with a string what ever is available at present.

Comment: That's an awful amount of nested `if`s --- plan on combining some of those conditions?

Answer (score -1):

Some time ago I had to analyse many FileZilla Server Logfiles with each >120MB.
I used a simple List to get all lines of each logfile and then had a great performance searching for specific lines.

```
List<string> fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile).ToList()
```

But in your case I think the main reason for the bad performance isn't  reading the file. Try to StopWatch some parts of your loop to check where the most time is spent. Regex and TryParse can be very time consuming if used many times in a loop like yours.

Comment: Actually my log file is not in same format through out the file.

Comment: i need to read file from one match pattern to another match pattern. Match patent is not always in the same line. there are line breaks in the  matching pattern string. so i need to use RegEx to identify the matching criteria. probably i need to figure out the way to optimize the RegEx that would improve the performance.